# Databinding to combo box WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind data to a combo box. The data is names from a table from database. Getting the data from the database works fine as I have tried to bind it to a List View and it displays fine. My problem is binding it to a combo box, it doesn't show anything.

Can anyone see where I have went wrong?

My code is the following...

```
   public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", _customer.ContactFirstName, _customer.ContactLastName);
        }
    }
```

and the XAML is

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FullName}" >
```

The XAML for it working with a list view is the following..

```
<ListView 
     AlternationCount="2" 
     DataContext="{StaticResource WorkorderGroups}" 
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource WorkorderItemStyle}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="1,0,-1,0>

     <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="WorkorderGroupStyle/>
     </ListView.GroupStyle>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FullName}" /> 
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Please post more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Bind a string to ComboBox. You need to bind some collection like `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` to combobox ItemsSource. Possible Duplicate.
Refer the link.
[Need SIMPLE working example of setting WPF MVVM ComboBox ItemsSource based on SelectedValue of second ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168068/need-simple-working-example-of-setting-wpf-mvvm-combobox-itemssource-based-on-se)

Comment: am thinking .. how did his ListView work .. isn't the same case with list view ?

Comment: @user3244139 Is `FullName` a `List<string>` ?