# Retrieving previously saved combobox items from wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF. below is the XAML code.

```
 <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
     <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cars" MinWidth="70" Width="70">
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Name="cboCars" MinWidth="70" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}" Width="70">
                    <ComboBoxItem>BMW</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Benz</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Audi</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So each row contains a combo box and it contains all the 3 car names are there as the combo box item and user can choose a car from the drop down and save it. But when taking back the value from the Database, I can't display the exact car in the grid row as the previously saved item.Suppose now if i choose "Audi" and save the form and later on when i tried to retrive the saved data, the combobox will be displaying nothing!!! How to show the exact car in the grid ?      Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need SIMPLE working example of setting WPF MVVM ComboBox ItemsSource based on SelectedValue of second ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168068/need-simple-working-example-of-setting-wpf-mvvm-combobox-itemssource-based-on-se)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at selection. You can define a property in your view model and bind it to the SelectedItem / SelectedValue of your combobox. After loading data you can set this property and this item is selected in your combobox.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168586/8002376